# Use Python3 "os" module on deployment?

Tags: python

I want to deploy my flask app to a azure web app and I use the module "os". When Iam generating the requirements.txt the "os" module isnt showing there. How can I use the "os" in the azure web app?

Comment: `os` is part of the standard library. Pretty sure you don't need to declare those.

Comment: I'll raise your "pretty sure you don't need to" to "You absolutely don't need to".

Answer (score 1):

The `os` module is part of the Python Standard Library and is therefore not included in the `requirements.txt` file as it does not need to be installed separately.

If you are trying to use the `os` module in your app, you can simply import it.

Comment: Edited slightly, as built-in modules are modules define as part of the implementation itself, rather than one created from an external file. `os.py` is, however, "pre-imported" by CPython. (`sys.modules['os']` is defined on startup, even if the name `os` isn't bound to it in the built-in scope.)